# New guitar intonation, is it impossible to achieve perfect intonation?

Tags: intonation

I have a new cordoba c3m i have problems with g string intonaton mostly, it doesnt match up the 12th fret, always a frequency difference here is results:

e open 329.5 e 12th 659.1

b open 246.8 b 12 th 493.4 (starts with 493.4 then descends little)

g open 195.8 g 12th 393.8

d open 146.9 d 12th 293.8 (starts a little sharper then descends)

a open 109.9 a 12th 220.0 (slight changes everytime)

e open 82.5 e 12th 165.0 (this is perfect)

and almost always when i pick a note or open string its a different freq everytime maybe 0.1 difference but its there

Comment: The way I do it is fret the 12th fret, and that note ought to be the same as the harmonic on that same fret. As a double check, I do the same at fret 19. Your way involves numbers, and I'm not good with sums! But, yes, it looks like the bridge is out. Simple solution - return it.

Comment: How old are the strings? They go out with age/dirt. ['new' doesn't tell us it hasn't been on the shop floor 6 months]

Comment: i dont know really how old are they but guitar looks completly new, ive heard that its impossible to get perfect intonation and and exact frequencies, so is it okay to continue with this? only g string is a little of 2 3 cents

Answer (score 2):

With traditional frets and a traditional nut, yes it is impossible for every fret and every string to be reasonably perfectly intonated to equal temperament.

With a compensated nut and movable frets (like these: http://www.tolgahancogulu.com/en/microtonal-guitar/), it should be possible to get arbitrarily close to perfect equal temperament.

Comment: Yep.  While a great deal can be done with compensating at the bridge (often done) and at the nut (rarely done), you really need moveable frets, and you need to adjust them differently for different string sets, in order to get really accurate intonation (equal temperament or other).